# How to display additional fields in user profile?

Tags: theming, users

I have added three fields to user profile (field_firstname, field_lastname, field_user_gender) and I want to display them on user profile page. Default `render($user_profile)` displays values of those fields continuously, for instance: *JohnMalkovichMale*

How I can do this right? And how I can get names of fields?

Comment: try enclosing them in `<pre></pre>` tag.

Comment: But what? `render($ser_profile)` ? I don't think so.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a CSS issue. Use developer tools/firebug to determine the class/id of the element wrapping each field, and add a CSS rule such as the following to your theme:

```
.field-wrapper-1, .field-wrapper-2 { display: block; }
```

Comment: No, it's not. There is no HTML markup. Just string 'JohnMalkovichMale'

Comment: Then your theme is overriding the output that it usually added to fields. Copy the [`field.tpl.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7) file to your theme's folder (make sure you have the markup from the link above in it), clear Drupal's caches and you'll be good to go